# Phaser Animation isn't working and freezing my game, frames from sprite sheet don't seem to load

Tags: javascript, animation, phaser-framework, sprite-sheet

I'm trying to have an eight-frame walking animation of a character in my game.

This is the code that loads the sprite sheet:

```
this.load.spritesheet('PeefSide', "assets/PeefSide.png", {frameWidth: 50, frameHeight: 
60, startFrame: 0, endFrame: 7});
```

This is the code that creates the sprite:

```
this.p1 = this.physics.add.sprite(500, 730, 'PeefSide');
```

This is the code that creates the animation:

```
this.anims.create({
        key: 'walk',
        frames: this.anims.generateFrameNumbers('peefSide', { start: 0, end: 7, first: 0}),
        frameRate: 10,
        repeat: -1
    });
```

And this is the code that plays the animation when the character moves:

```
if(this.keyA.isDown) {
        this.p1.setVelocityX(-200);
        this.p1.anims.play('walk', true);
    }
```

I'm not sure what I've done wrong, but when I run the game, it freezes when I press a move button. The inspection screen says that the error is trying to read properties of undefined and before the error occurs, it says:

generateFrameNumbers: Frame 0 missing from texture: peefSide

It repeats this line for every frame, the number going up one, then the game freezing error happens when a move button is pressed. Really not sure what went wrong.

If it helps find an answer, I'm using Phaser 3 in VSCode employing arcade physics.

Comment: Did you already had the opportunity to check, if my answer solve your problem? Or is something still not working?

Comment: I've gotten past this problem. thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, that the **key** used in `this.anims.generateFrameNumbers('peefSide',...)`, doesn't match the actual **key** from the load `this.load.spritesheet('PeefSide',...)`, because the **key** is *case-sensitive*.

You would have to use the UpperCase '**P**' like this `this.anims.generateFrameNumbers('PeefSide',...)`

This should fix the Warning:

> generateFrameNumbers: Frame 0 missing from texture: peefSide

And this will also solve the freezing issue, because now the animation will be actually playing, before because it culdn't find the frames, it showed the initial frame.